# Find range of $f(x)=3|\sin x|-4|\cos x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Find range of the function $$f(x)=3|\sin x|-4|\cos x|$$

I tried to do by using the trigonometric identities $$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2};\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$$

So $$f(x)=3\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}}-4\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}}$$ but don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=3|\sin x| -4|\cos x|$;

$-4 \le -4|\cos x| \le f(x) \le$

$3|\sin x| \le 3;$

By inspection:

$f(π/2)= 3$; $f(0)=-4$;

Range$_f =[-4,3]$.

Answer (score 4):

$f(0)=-4$, $f(\pi/2)=3$ and $$-4\leq f(x)\leq 3,$$

for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Intermediate value theorem gives $f(\mathbb R)=[-4,3]$.

Comment: Why have you invoked the Intermediate value theorem

Comment: because this justify that $f(\mathbb R)=[-4,3]$ @Maverick

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x)=3|\sin x|-4|\cos x|$$
It's easy to show $f(x)$ is periodic with $T = \pi$ and $f(x)$ is even. So it's enough to consider $0\le x\le\pi/2$.

If $0\le x\le\pi/2$ then 
$$0\le\sin x\le1  \implies 0\le|\sin x|\le1$$
And 
$$0\le\cos x\le1  \implies 0\le|\cos x|\le1$$
Therefore we have $-4\le f(x) \le 3$ but this could be only an upper bound not the actual range.

If $0\le x\le\pi/2$ then
$$f(x) = 3\sin x-4\cos x \implies f'(x) = 3\cos x + 4\sin x \gt 0 \implies \ \ \ \\ f(0)\le f(x) \le f(\pi/2)  \implies -4\le f(x) \le 3$$

Confirming the first result. Actually because $f(x)$ is an increasing function in that interval, the results are the same. So we can conclude that $-4\le f(x) \le 3$ and [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%7Csin%20x%7C%20-%204%7Ccos%20x%7C) verifies that.